# nhibernate giving mysql errors - but still working fine

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

any idea why I am getting this in my logs on startup?

> Blockquote
>   ERROR NHibernate.Util.ReflectHelper - Could not load type MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection, MySql.Data.
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   File name: 'MySql.Data'
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
>      at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
>      at NHibernate.Util.ReflectHelper.TypeFromAssembly(AssemblyQualifiedTypeName name, Boolean throwOnError) in c:\Users\oskar.berggren\Documents\Projects\nhibernate-core-3\src\NHibernate\Util\ReflectHelper.cs:line 280
>   Blockquote

but it works perfectly fine. I am using FluentNhibernate to config my app

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate uses DBProviderFactories as a fall back if loaing using reflection does not work. it could be that it logs the failing attempt even when it is able to load it.